# Hide content inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my situation.

I have a file called iframe.html. which has code in below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Pluign Development</title>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <iframe id="abc" src="test.html"></iframe>
        <div id="sub">click</div>
    </body>

    <script src="js/script-22.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

and i have test.html file. which has code in below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Pluign Development</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="red">prasanga karunanayake </div>
    </body>


</html>
```

here is js code what i have tried,

```
(function($){ 

    var fire = {
        init:function(){
            $('#sub')
            .on('click', function(){
                $('#red', parent.document).css('display','none');
            });
        }
    };
    fire.init();

}(jQuery));
```

Here is my situation.

i need to hide `<div id="red">prasanga karunanayake </div>` which is in the test.html file. if i click `<div id="sub">click</div>`  then hide html content which is in the test.html.

I am pretty much confused,Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I suspect hiding the iframe itself is out of the question?

Comment: You mean you need to hide `<div id="red">prasanga karunanayake </div> ` on clicking `<div id="sub">click</div>` and nothing else?

Comment: try this $('#red', window.parent.document).css('display','none');

Answer (score 12):

You can use `.contents()` this way:

```
$('#abc').contents().find('#red').hide();
```

---

Another thing is, As you have wrapped your code in a closure which runs as page response gets in the browser. So it might be possible that this code change would not work.

Instead i suggest you to put a dom ready block also for this:

```
(function($){ 
    $(function(){ // <---add this block from here to
      var fire = {
        init:function(){
            $('#sub').on('click', function(){
                $('#abc').contents().find('#red').hide();
            });
        }
      };
      fire.init();
  }); //<----here
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
   $('#sub')
    .on('click', function(){
        $('iframe #red').css('display','none');
    });
```

**EDIT**
First fetch the event when the iframe has loaded, then create an event handler to capture clicks on the #sub div, and finally find red in the loaded iframe and hide it

```
$(function(){
            var f=$('#abc')
            f.load(function(){ 
                  $("#sub").click(function(){
                     f.contents().find('#red').hide(); 
                  });

            })
        })
```

Comment: Thanks your answer but here is thing i need hide html content. if i click div.

Answer (score 2):

If the page loaded inside the iframe is not in the same domain as the parent frame, then it's not possible using JavaScript or CSS.

This is a security feature implemented on web browsers to prevent XSS (Cross site scripting).

Comment: Has the problem been fixed?

Comment: Nothing. I'm very nice if can help you.

Answer (score -3):

You can't hide what's in the iframe per se but you can hide the iframe by changing the src, like this:

```
$('#sub')
        .on('click', function(){
            $('#abc').attr('src','');
        });
```