# jQuery - Trying to hide element inside frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <head>
  <title>Test 2</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>


<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="wishlist.html">
  <frame name="frame1" src="shortcodes.html">
  <frame src="portfolio.html">
</frameset>

</html>
```

In frame with name `frame1` i have element called `testId`.
All i want is to hide the element with id `testId` inside frame with name `frame1`.

So far i have tried this:

```
$("#testId", $("#frame1").contents()).hide();
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working. Why i can not hide the element when i run this line of code ?

Is it even possible?

Comment: You have not given ID to frame, use `$("#testId", $("[name=frame1]").contents()).hide();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide content inside iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the frame with a name:

```
<frame name="frame1" src="shortcodes.html">
```

but you are looking for an id with jquery.
Change your HTML in this way

```
<frame id="frame1" src="shortcodes.html">
```

Or change your jquery in this way:

```
$("#testId", $("[name=frame1]").contents()).hide();
```

If this doesn't work, access the content in this way:

```
$($('[name="frame1"]', top.document)[0].contentDocument).find('*').hide();
```

Then avoid the use of the `frameset` because it is deprecated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: Tried the suggestion you gave but it is not working. The element is not hiding.

Comment: where/when do you execute this script?

Comment: can you paste me the code, showing where do you call that jQuery script please?

Comment: I wait everything to load and i execute it the browser console.

Comment: with everything you mean also the iFrame?
like `$("#frame1").ready(function (){
    $(this).contents()).hide();
});`

Comment: Yes and i execute it directly in the browser's console. Like if you click F12 and write `alert("Hello")` you receive alert message saying `Hello`, but i put the code you provided instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144940/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-quirimmo).