# Hide "Watch on Youtube" from thumbnail in embeded youtube iframe before playing

Tags: css, video, youtube, embed

I embeded youtube video using iframe with autoplay off.

Before play, it shows "Watch on Youtube" image at bottom of thumbnail along with Play icon at center of thumbnail.

How to remove this watch on youtube.

css apepars to be .ytp-impression-link but its inside iframe.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Try `.ytp-impression-link{display:none;}`

Comment: Already tried but didn't work. Apparently couldn't apply css as this element inside iframe dynamically loaded by youtube

Comment: Try adding `!important ` propery

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Didn't work

Comment: Are you sure the class is `.ytp-impression-link{display:none;}`

Comment: Do you know Why this not working .. Beacause it is loading in IFrame not in Native HTML .. Also I agree with you .. It is class is `.ytp-impression-link` .. So my goal is how to hide content inside iFrame

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow .. After a lot of research I did not find answer but I find stuff like below :

First : You can hide content inside iFrame using JavaScript (Like [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232839/14945696) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232797/14945696))

Second : Why we cannot hide Watch on YouTube in Youtube iFrame .. Reason : There is something called Cross Site Scripting which it not allowed on all Major Browsers it is only allowed if the iframe on your own (Like iFrame `Src="index.html"` not `Src="youtube.com"` in your domain not other domain) So in case of Youtube we cannot hide it .. Sorry

Attribution for @MinhNhậtPhan in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46700903/14945696) for information About Cross Site Scripting .. That is All.