# How to use Google Form as website "login" page

Tags: html, css, authentication, google-forms

I know this may sound weird. I want to use Google Form (two inputs, name and email) as a "fake" login page. The website is a simple one-page HTML, no CMS, no database. When users visit the page, they must submit the form every time. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is embed a google form into your website, here's how:

1. Create a google form with the description you said (i.e name, email...)
2. When you are done creating the form, click the purple `send` button on the top right of the site, then click on the `<>` script icon and copy the iframe code
3. Paste this code onto your website
4. Every time a person answers your google form on your website, their response will be sent to you via email

NOTE: This is much easier done if you just share the google form, instead of creating a whole website.

This is the code demo: https://codepen.io/carldjapardi/pen/poeeEdq

Comment: Thanks Its Fragilis. My further question is how to hide the main content of the website before the user submits the form. 

Use 100% viewport height and width to max the iframe, so the iframe will cover the main content. Then use JS to add class: hidden; to iframe once the user clicks on the submit button. Can I target submit button inside the iframe to toggle class?

Comment: I got HTML and CSS right. Now I need to find out how to hide the iframe when users click on submit button. Any idea?
https://codepen.io/TianxuanL/pen/mdWmbBK

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232738/hide-content-inside-iframe